# Woocommerce related product text change

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi im currently using Wordpress with woocommerce installed and have a problem im sure some of you know of :)

Hi guys im currently using this in my function.php

```
 // Change WooCommerce "Related products" text

add_filter('gettext', 'change_rp_text', 10, 3);
add_filter('ngettext', 'change_rp_text', 10, 3);

function change_rp_text($translated, $text, $domain)
{
 if ($text === 'Related products' && $domain === 'woocommerce') {
     $translated = esc_html__('You may also like..', $domain);
 }
 return $translated;
}
```

It works very well, however i want to add two dots after "You may also like", however it will only return one.. How can i achieve this?

Is it possible to have two dots after each other with "esc_html__"? how could i receive it in another way if this doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

```
// CHANGE RELATED PRODUCTS TEXT
function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
switch ( $translated_text ) {
    case 'Related products' :
        $translated_text = __( 'You may also like&hellip', 'woocommerce' );
        break;
}
return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3 );
```

Comment: Doesn't work, will output the same as before "You may also like." with only one dot.

Comment: Oh it doesnt it only adds space between the dots.

Comment: Its like doing this "You may also like . . ."

Comment: please check ans

Comment: Hmm only returns one dot again, this is a rather hard problem to solve :D

Comment: Two dot leader makes space between dots, so it looks like "You may also like. ."

Comment: Remove 3 dots and add only 2 dots as your requirements

Comment: What u mean Ravi?

Comment: Just copy my ans and paste

Comment: it outputs "You may also like&hellip"

Comment: wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/related.php             In this file you can change your word Please  try